# How to deep copy unsigned long

Tags: c++

I have this class

```
typedef unsigned long Item;
class Stack
{
private:
    enum { MAX = 10} ;   
    Item  * pitems;     
    int size;           
    int top;         
public:
    Stack(int n = 10);  
    Stack(const Stack & st);
};
```

How to I make a deep copy of `Item`?
Is this right?

```
pitems = st.pitems;

Stack::Stack(const Stack & st){
size = st.size;
pitems = new Item[size + 1];
pitems = st.pitems;
top = st.top;}
```

Comment: Do you want to copy the items or the pointer ? Currently it seems like you just set the pointer. IMO you'll have a memory leak.

Comment: I want to copy the items.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Loop through them and copy them, not the pointer of the other class.

```
Stack::Stack(const Stack &st)
{
    this->size      = st.size;
    this->top       = st.top;
    this->pitems    = new Item[this->size + 1];
    for (auto i = 0; i < this->size; ++i)
    {
        pitems[i] = st.pitems[i];
    }
}
```

As mentioned in the comment before, you currently have a memory leak.

Answer (score 2):

No, you need to loop through each of the items in the old array and create new copies for the new array.

```
for(int i = 0; i != size; ++i)
{
    pitems[i] = st.pitems[i]; //Assuming you have an equals operator for Item
}
```

And definitely do not do `pitems = st.pitems;` as this leaks the new array you made with `new Item[size + 1]`